# push segue to two page from one cell in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I create one page tableViewController and I want when to click on cell go on to two page with condition (for example when index.row < 5 go to firstViewController with push style transition  and when index.row >= 5 go on to another TableViewController with push style transition)

I dont know about this. please tell me more about that.

Comment: What about [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue" sender: self]?

Answer (score 1):

You require `UIViewController` to `UIViewController` segue.

Instead of giving segue on `UITableViewCell` Give segue on `UIViewController`

**Give proper identifier to this segue in inspector.**

Now you can use this segue as you want.

So in your case you can code something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if(<CONDITION>)
     {
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier_1" sender:self];
     }
     else 
     {
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier_1" sender:self];
     }
}
```

This is not your exact code so edit it as per your need.

All the best.....

Comment: my friend do connect both segue on the cell

Comment: But why on cell only what is problem in viewcontroller?

Comment: my friend I want go on to next page and next page maybe is UIViewController or UITableViewController

Comment: Ya so what problem? 1 segue will br viewcontroller to viewcontroller and second seguw will be viewcontroller to tableviewcontroller.

Comment: no I have tableview and I want 1 segue for connecting UITableView with UITableView and 1 segue for connecting UITableView with UIViewController .also I want to be these segues push style transition

Comment: If u want "push style transition" that give segue type push. It hase nothing to do with UItableViewCell or UIViewController. and your UITableView is not alone it is in a UIViewController. your UITableView can trigger segue but it is always perform by UIViewController and UINavigationController.

Comment: I am not getting why u have problem in giving segue on VC to VC and perform on row selection. This is very common and we have done it very often.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create the two `Push segues` in your `Storyboard`, each to link the two controllers you want to navigate to (don't forget to assign a right identifier for both). Then, in your tableview cell click event, you would have something like this.-

```
if (index.row < 5) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSegueIdentifier1 sender:nil];
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSegueIdentifier2 sender:nil];
}
```

Comment: I use this code but when I put in storyboard 2 segue push this code is crashed!!!

Comment: my friend do connect both segue on the cell